# Python Dataframe Conditional Sum

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe incomeData with Country, Region and Income. I am attempting to use aggregation to return mean, min, max and counts. I want to be able to count the countries where the income is greater than 100.

```
raw_data = {'Country': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
            'Region': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'],
            'Income': [100, 200, 300, 100, 200]
           }
incomeData = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Country', 'Region', 'Income'])
regionGroup = incomeData.groupby(['Region'], as_index=False)
groupCount = lambda x: x.count()
#CountHighIncome = ?
aggregations = {
    'Country': {groupCount
    },
    'Income': {'min', 'max', 'mean', 'median' #, CountHighIncome
    }
}
incomeSummary = regionGroup.agg(aggregations)
incomeSummary
```

```
   Region  Country Income

            lambda> median  max mean min CountHighIncome

0   X       3       200     300 200  100 2

1   Y       2       150     200 150  100 1
```

Please let me know if the lambda approach to count countries within a region can be extended to count countries within a region where the income is greater than 100. Or if there is an alternative better approach to this problem.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom function with `lambda` with sum condition, `True`s are count like `1`, also for `Country` is removed `lambda` function and is used `count` only:

```
CountHighIncome = lambda x: (x > 100).sum()
aggregations = {
    'Country': {'count'
    },
    'Income': {'min', 'max', 'mean', 'median',  CountHighIncome
    }
}
incomeSummary = regionGroup.agg(aggregations)
print (incomeSummary)
  Region Income                           Country
            max  min <lambda> mean median   count
0      X    300  100        2  200    200       3
1      Y    200  100        1  150    150       2
```

Comment: Thank you, your response is well appreciated. This works a treat.